# Vue 2: URL not refreshing properly the second time

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the next views:

- **/dashboard** with a list with links. When link is clicked redirects with Router to "/projects/:projectId".
- **/projects/:projectId** with a text with the projectId

When I click the button, the first load, works everything properly. 
If I go again to dashboard and click the icon again, the page loads properly (the content) but the URL does not show /projects/:projectId. It shows "/".

My Router:

```
    {
        path: "/dashboard",
        name: "Dashboard",
        component: Dashboard,
        meta: {layout: "MainLayout"}
    },
    {
        path: "/project/:projectId",
        name: "ViewProject",
        component: () => import (/* webpackChunkName: "ViewProject" */ "../views/projects/ViewProject.vue"),
        meta: {layout: "MainLayout"}
```

When the button is clicked:

```
    public selectProject(id:number){
      this.$router.push("/project/"+id);
    }
```

I realized that if I press back in the browswer, the URL appears with no changing on the page, looks like somehow it is pushing 2 times a value, the second time empty.

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: have you tried using "router.push" instead of "router.replace"

Comment: Hi @Evan thx, by mistake I put router.replace in the question, but I tried with everything, it does exactly the same behave.

Comment: I can't Replicate so it's hard to pinpoint exactly what's wrong. if you can replicate this in a  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/ it would easier for people to answer.

Comment: @Evan The problem is that I can't reproduce it in jsfiddle because there is no address bar. If you ask the value of "self.location" answers "localhost:8080/#/project/1" when in the address bar shows "localhost:8080/#/"

Comment: @Evan thanks, finally I found the solution, just posted for other people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem.
This was my link:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" @click="selectProject(project.id)">Select</a>
```

This was the code of select project:

```
public selectProject(id:number){
   this.$router.push("project/"+id);
}
```

By default, Vue executes the "click" method and then the "href" of the link, in my case, redirecting to "#". Becase there is no id after the # was only redirected once, but the address was replaced.

Solution:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="selectProject(project.id)">Select</a>
```